# Change zoom setting of IE for web-scraping with VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to do web scraping with VBA and have a following error:

Do

```
Dim driver As New webdriver
driver.Start '"ie"
```

Then
[image]

I fixed "internet option" setting and reset settings to default. I also checked registry settings, but it was already set to 100%.
However, every time I open IE, its zoom ratio is set to 200%.
What codes can I add in VBA, or which setting should I change?

Comment: you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value

Comment: You can refer to this doc to see if you have met all the [Required Configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) before automating IE in selenium. It also says *For Windows 10, you also need to set "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to 100% in display settings.* You must meet all the requirements so that InternetExplorerDriver can work well.

Comment: QHarr, Thanks, 
Yu Zhou, Yes, that is what I am struggling at. I confirm that the setting is all 100%, but the IE enlarges to 200% when I tried to open the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is not a good solution but I connected the PC to the external monitor, which solved the problem.